# Java JUnit assertEquals expected:<* by zero> but was:<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: * by zero>

Tags: java, testing, junit

I can't get this custom JUnit test to work correctly with this custom exception. It's just to help myself clear the concepts, nothing useful in terms of actual utility. Can't figure it out and can't find any direct online help so figured I'd ask here. What's going on?

```
@Test
    void testMultiply_WhenFourIsMultipiedByZero_ShouldThrowException() {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 4;
        String expectedMsg = "* by zero";

        Exception e = assertThrows(
                expectedMsg,
                IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
                    tm.multiply(i, j);
                });

        assertEquals("Error", expectedMsg, e);
//      assertEquals(expectedMsg, expectedMsg, e.getMessage()); //this leads to a different error "Method assertEquals(String, Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type"

    }
```

```
public int multiply(int i, int j) throws Exception {
        
        if(i == 0 || j == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("* by zero");
        }
        
        return i * j;
    }
```

Even if I try this it doesn't work.
Error:
java.lang.AssertionError: Error expected: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: * by zero> but was: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: * by zero>

```
void testMultiply_WhenFourIsMultipiedByZero_ShouldThrowException() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 4;
    String expectedMsg = "* by zero";
    
    IllegalArgumentException f = new IllegalArgumentException("* by zero"); 

    IllegalArgumentException e = assertThrows("expectedMsg",
            
            IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
                tm.multiply(i, j);
            });
    
    assertEquals("Error", f, e);
}
```

Edit:
Got it to work with the following. Evidently string objects can't be compared using assertEquals. If anyone can explain why, I'd appreciate it but got it to work anyway.

```
    assertTrue(actualMessage.equals(expectedMsg));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
assertEquals("Error", expectedMsg, e);
```

expectedMsg is instance of String & e is instance of IllegalArgumentException class. You are comparing **String object** with **IllegalArgumentException object**.

assertEqual() error is just displaying that.

Correct code would be

assertEquals("Error", expectedMsg, e.getMessage());

Comment: When I change it to that, I get a different error : Method assertEquals(String, Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type className.

Comment: i ran the whole thing in my setup,. it just worked fine.